# New job offer immediate start UK

Tags: interviewing, new-job, resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I have an interview tomorrow and they sounded very desperate. It is a job I have wanted for 10 years. I have started a different job 2 months ago. If I get this job the training will start the day after the interview. This means I would have to resign with immediate effect. The job I’m interviewing for it is rare for positions to become available. I have my shifts right up to the end of June for my current job. What should I do? What would be the consequences of resigning with immediate effect? What’s the best way to do it?

I forgot to mention that my current job ends in November with little chance of getting offered a permanent position and this new one is a permanent position

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also, this is a potential duplicate of: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110653/new-job-starts-before-the-end-of-notice-period-at-my-present-job

Comment: And this one: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98314/new-job-starts-before-end-of-current-jobs-notice-period

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New job starts before end of current job's notice period](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98314/new-job-starts-before-end-of-current-jobs-notice-period)

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd really question an employer that expected you **not** to work out a notice period at your current job.  Even if this is your dream job, that doesn't seem right, and if it were me it wouldn't be a company I'd want to work at just for that requirement.

Given that you've only worked at this job for 2-months, and you really want this job, I'd definitely consider doing it though.  Just don't expect any favors from your current job (PTO paid out, letter of recommendation, etc.)  In fact, never expect to work there again.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. They had already booked the course date and had 3 people but one dropped out last minute so they offered me an interview. That’s why i won’t be able to work my notice period as the other 2 are expecting to start then.

Answer (score -1):

> So Mr. Future Employer, how much more is it worth to you for me to burn a bridge with my current employer?

Then let them answer that question with a dollar amount.

Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the idea here, but it seems challenging for the OP to put a dollar figure on burning that bridge, in order to know if the new employer's offer is worthwhile.

Comment: ^^^ Indeed, but if you say it diplomatically enough it will fly, and if they balk the OP can always follow up with 'How would you feel if I eventually left your employment with zero notice?'

Comment: Let me rephrase/extend my thought. Would you suggest to the OP that he reject the new company's offer if the dollar amount was "not big enough?" What would he do then - stay put? Or hope that he still has an offer at the new company, and take it anyways?

Answer (score -2):

If your contract doesn't specify a notice period, two weeks is generally considered the standard (at least in the US). If you choose to leave immediately, you can probably consider the bridge with your old employer burned.  Remember the golden rule--you probably wouldn't consider it fair for your company to terminate your employment with no notice. They would feel the same way about you doing this to them. If the new company really wants you, they should be willing to wait two weeks as this would be a requirement for the majority of applicants sans those who are currently unemployed.  See if you can negotiate the start date.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It is very rare for a vacancy to open up and if I turn it down I don’t know when the next position will arise. They have 3 positions and have already hired 2. They have booked the training for a set date which cannot be changed

Comment: -1 Answer not useful: US and UK are miles apart in employment law.